# Small discrepancy in Advanced Search help in Firefox

Tags: bug, search, firefox, help

In Firefox (currently running 25.0.1), When you click on the Advanced Search Tips on the right-hand side of the display after you have searched for something, you get the following for the url search tip:

[image: url search tip]

Note that it starts with a double-quote and looks like it ends with a single quote.  If you cut and paste the text into Notepad you can see that it actually is a double quote.  This is probably related to all the other Firefox Stack Exchange display bugs that have been reported before and I constantly see; so, one more data point.

Comment: Not for me in Chrome 31.

Comment: Did they just fix this? I can't see it.

Comment: Ah, looks like it's a Firefox bug, will edit this Q.  probably related to the textbox overflow bug also (and many other SO Firefox display bugs).

Comment: I don't see it in my Firefox 26 either. That's on Win8.

Comment: [No repro on Firefox 26, Windows 7](http://i.imgur.com/adOUXec.png)